# I have a grid layout and would like to merge two columns

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

So I'm using divs for columns and want to merge two "cells" so to speak. I have a layout of what I want below and want to merge the bottom two divs into one div.

I cannot post an image so here is a link to what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIgNV.jpg

the following is my html code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="width1 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width1 height2 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width1 height1 grid_item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="width1 height2 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width1 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width1 height1 grid_item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width2 height2 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width2 height1 grid_item" style="text-align:right">merge --&gt;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="width1 height3 grid_item"></div>
        <div class="width1 height1 grid_item"> &lt;--merge</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

and the following is my css:

```
.height1{
height:160px;

}
.height2{
height:320px;   
}
.height3{
height:484px;   
}
.width1{
width:174px;
}
.width2{
width:213px;
}
.width3{
width:391px;
position:relative;
float:inherit;  
}
.grid_item{
margin:2px;
background-color:green;
}
.column{
position:relative;
float: left;    
}
```

Comment: Tables are terrible for layout but they aren't something we should just throw away in HTML and never use. Tables are great at tabular data. If you're trying to make a grid of data (which is what it appears) use a table.

Comment: Thats why I have it as a div, maybe the word merge is not the right one here, but its the same concept

Comment: Solved it, if anyone needs help with the same question let me know

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar situation. Can you please share as to how you solve this problem.

Comment: I created a div that heald the two columns on the right, then there were two dive, one to hold the one on the bottom and another on the top . you could look at the following website; I am not using it any more but it should help. check the source code out: http://interscalegroup.com/archive/new2/